# In R, subset rows of a matrix to get a list

Tags: r, subset

I have a `matrix M`, the first `5 rows` and `columns` are given below

```
       [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
[1,] 0.00000000 3.249741e-01 3.288171e-01 3.330941e-01 1.183995e-01
[2,] 0.33606769 2.220446e-16 3.788052e-02 1.891638e-02 2.669093e-01
[3,] 0.41547944 2.514113e-02 2.220446e-16 6.044581e-03 3.363015e-01
[4,] 0.36944317 1.783518e-02 2.043331e-02 1.110223e-16 2.790867e-01
[5,] 0.02374292 2.911900e-01 2.983280e-01 3.102164e-01 1.110223e-16
```

The full matrix is much bigger.

I would like to subset each `row` of `M` to include only the `columns` with values larger than `0.3`. So for example from `row 1` I want to keep 2, 3, 4, from `row 2` only 1 and 3, and so on.
Since each row would contain a different number of elements, the result would be a `list`.

How can I do this efficiently for very large `matrices` (i.e. no loop but  subsetting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be change the elements that are less than 0.3 to NA

```
replace(M, M <= 0.3, NA)
```

Or

```
M *(NA ^(M <= 0.3))
```

---

If we need a `list` output, create a logical matrix, extract the values in 'M' based on the index, and `split` by the `row` of the `matrix`

```
ind <- M > 0.3
split(M[ind], row(M)[ind])
```

The easiest option would be

```
apply(M, 1, function(x) x[x > 0.3])
```

Or another option is to `melt` the `matrix` into 'long' format, `filter` based on the 'value' column, `summarise` into a `list` after grouping by 'Var1' (row index)

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
melt(M) %>% 
    filter(value > 0.3) %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>% 
    summarise(value = list(value))
```

Comment: But how do I get the final list?